# Why dependency injection only work on @Service and @Contract, how to change or add some other annotation like @Singleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

There is an application that is configured by hk2 dependency injection.
the pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <junit.version>5.4.0</junit.version>
    <jsonassert.version>1.5.0</jsonassert.version>
    <jersey.version>3.0.2</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Grizzly 2 HTTP Server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey DI and core-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-metadata-generator</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- add jackson as json provider -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to hide warning for jakarta.activation.DataSource -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test json data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>${jsonassert.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and MyResource.java:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.mkyong.json.service.MessageService;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class MyResource {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Inject
    @Named("aws")
    private MessageService awsService;

    @Inject
    @Named("azure")
    private MessageService azureService;

    @Path("/hk2/aws")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String helloAws() {
        String result = awsService.getHello();

        ObjectNode json = mapper.createObjectNode();
        return result;
    }

    @Path("/hk2/azure")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String helloAzure() {
        return azureService.getHello();
    }

}
```

and AutoScanFeature.java :

```
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Populator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.DuplicatePostProcessor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AutoScanFeature implements Feature {

    @Inject
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

        DynamicConfigurationService dcs =
                serviceLocator.getService(DynamicConfigurationService.class);
        Populator populator = dcs.getPopulator();
        try {
            // Populator - populate HK2 service locators from inhabitants files
            // ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder - find files from META-INF/hk2-locator/default
            populator.populate(
                    new ClasspathDescriptorFileFinder(this.getClass().getClassLoader()),
                    new DuplicatePostProcessor());

        } catch (IOException | MultiException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AutoScanFeature.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Service interface:

```
@Contract
public interface UserService {
    void add(User user);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        super.save(user, hibernateOracleTestXML);
    }
}
```

Everything is working correctly and dependency injection is only worked by only `@Service` and `@Contract`, but I want to use `@Singleton` or something else for such as DAO layer.

Another hand It does not work when I use `@Singleton` or something else except `@Service`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Contract` and `@Service` are both for its default injection, according to the question, these annotations are not suitable for DAO layer, so I solved this issue by `org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder` like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure() {

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName);

        Set<Class<?>> repositories = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Repository.class, true);

        repositories.stream().forEach(repo -> {

            BeanAddress beanAddresses = repo.getAnnotationsByType(BeanAddress.class)[0];

            try {
                Class<?> requiredClass = Class.forName(beanAddresses.implPackageName());
                bind(requiredClass).to(repo)
                        .named(Class.class.getCanonicalName()).in(Singleton.class);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
...
```

As it shows, I manually bind the interface to its class of DAO layers by an annotation that is made by myself(`BeanAddress.class`)